# Debug a single PHP file with $_GET parameters in NetBeans/Eclipse/PHPstorm (AJAX API)

Tags: php, ajax, eclipse, netbeans, phpstorm

This should be straightfoward, but Googe is not helpful today.

I have a PHP Ajax API, with a series if separate files, each of which accepts its parameters through $_GET.

How do I feed those parameters when I debug a file?

(btw, XDEBUG is working fine, it launches a browser when I tell NetBeans to debug the file; I just can't see how to pass parameters to the URL Which is launched)

---

[Update] I will also accept an answer for Eclipse and even for PHP Storm, which I will buy if I can't find a free solution.

---

[Update++] ***Please***, realize that I want to be able to stop on breakpoints in the IDE. Some answers here seem to have somehow missed that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using $_GET parameters then you can simply use a browser with an Xdebug helper plugin eg https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en

Your GET parameters can be coded into a request directly into the address bar and then when you visit teh page via your browser, you can debug the script as it runs.

Running Xdebug this way - from the browser - is a much simpler and more intuitive way of working.

PHPStorm is the best IDE that I'm aware of for getting Xdebug working

Comment: I installed it, enabled it, set a breakpoint in NetBeans & it was not hit. Do I have to add something to the URL? There don't seem to be any docs with this :-(

Comment: Done, but it didn't hit a breakpoint in PhpStorm at the start of the script. Goven the paucity of information on the wesite, can you help me to get it working?

Comment: Are you sure your break point is actually even happening. Set a break point at the top of your script

Comment: I have done so. I set a breakpoint at the start of the PHP file in PhpStorm, then loaded the file in the browser with the plugin enabled :-(

Comment: Settings/IDE key seems to be important, although setting it to PhpStorm still didn't stop on my brealpoint :-(

Comment: Right click on the icon, select the IDE, left clcik on the icon and load the page, adding &XDEBUG_PROFILE=PHPSTORM. I can verify that that works, and so award the answer. It doesn't seem to work with NetBeans, but I will try that and post here if I can get it to work.

Comment: Netbeans is trickier to get working. PHPstorm is awesome anyway so you won't regret going for it

Comment: Agreed. But not everyone can afford it. If you know how to get NetBeans working, could you please post it to help others? Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: I haven't used netbeans in years in afraid. However, check this out for free phpstorm. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/51185764

Comment: Is that "PhpStorm Early Access Program" a free, time limited beta? When I look at pricing of the standard product,  they give a "price for first year". So, I don't just buy it, but keep on paying (licensing)? Do you know if the price goes up or down in subsequent years?

Comment: And, do you know if JetBrains have an IDE where I can code & debug bot PHP and JS and breakpoint both, load a URL and stop on whichever breakpoint is hit first?

Comment: I always use chrome for js debugging, though phpstorm does support it apparently https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/debugging-javascript.html

Comment: Wow!  I think you just answered my question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21624/ide-to-develop-ajax-angularjs-and-php  THANKS !!!!

Comment: Aaargh!! This answer was working for me, then I renooted and now it does not work any more :-(  It won't even hit a breakpoint on the frst line of the code :-(

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code has this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) to debug the code. I used to debug the but haven't yet feed any data during debug. You should get this easily.

Comment: I was unable to add comment to the question (due to privileges), hence answered here

Comment: So you are saying that it _might_ work, but you have never tried it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have done this before in Visual Studio (not VS Code) but that might require paid plugin in which you can change the values of variables during debug.

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm has zero-configuration setup for XDebug described here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm. All you is to setup xdebug (you've already done), enable incoming connections by pressing button with handset icon, set breakpoint and run script.

Update: Configuring XDegub on local maching could be a little messy on first time, so here some things to clarify manual above:
1. make sure you have these config lines in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=IDEA
```

ideakey could be anything you like.

2. Enable XDebug incoming connections in PHPStorm: [image: screen1]
3. Enable XDebug listener: [image: screen2]
4. Set breakpoint by leftclick near line number: [image: screen3]
5. Send common request as always. First time here be promt of incoming connections, just press "Accept": [image: screen4]

And debugger will stop at breakpoint so you could inspect runtime enviroment. Also check Jeffrey Way's tutorial videos about setup XDebug in PHPStrom: https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/19 and https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/20

Comment: This looks very good, thanks (+1), but I can't figre out step 4. Activate debugger on server. Do I just add somethijng to my URL? What? I am using GET.

Comment: You may simply add XDEBUG_PROFILE=you_ide_key (`PHPSTORM` by default, it could be configured in IDE) GET parameter or use bookmark helper as described under `How to add "Start/Stop Debugging" bookmarklets to your browser bookmarks toolbar` cut in manual.

Comment: Sorry for no screenshots, I am from phone now and will be able to add more details later

Comment: Added screenshots with explainings, hope this will help.

Comment: Excellent! I will check it this evening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use poster plugin in firefox its very helpful.
[image: helpful image]

Comment: Do you have a URL for this plugin?